# IntelliJ not reflecting Maven dependencies

Tags: intellij-idea

I recently updated my `IntelliJ` and I am having a problem with it showing import statements as nonexistent in the classpath despite the project building fine by doing `mvn clean [install|verify]` from the command line and the software actually works. So the dependencies are certainly there but the IDE seems to have a bug synchronizing against the pom file. I have tried to `Maven --> Reimport` multiple times, without success.

Considering that I recently updated IntelliJ (the version is as of 7/15/2017), could this be a newly introduced bug and is there a workaround?

Comment: Have you invalidated your caches?

Comment: No. Should I and how is it done?

Comment: `File -> Invalidate caches / Restart`. NB: you'll lost you local changes history.

Comment: File > Invalidate Caches / Restart.  I don't want to make this an answer since IntelliJ has lost its mind and that *usually* helps, but not *always*.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175852 may be the case, it's fixed in https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2017.2+EAP.

Comment: I did invalidate caches and it didn't solve the problem

Comment: Does 2017.2.1 EAP help?

Comment: @CrazyCoder -- what is `2017.2.1 EAP` ?

Comment: The link to 2017.2.1 EAP is just 4 comments above.

Comment: so, before I venture into downloading this -- let me clarify -- this is essentially a beta version that has not been officially published yet and it contains a fix for the bug I'm dealing with, correct ?

Comment: I installed the EAP -- it looks like the problem is gone.  So it is a bug in the official latest version. @CrazyCoder -- if you post it in an answer, i will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be caused by a [known bug in Maven integration](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175852) which affects 2017.2 version. This bug is fixed in [2017.2.1 version](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2017.2+EAP).

You can find out if it's the case of your problem by searching [`idea.log`](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.embedder.CustomModelValidator$ProxyModelProblemCollector.add(Lorg/apache/maven/model/building/ModelProblemCollectorRequest;)V
```